# Maps pointer is not showing by phonegap build

Tags: google-maps, phonegap-build

In Google Maps, whenever i search by a latitude and longitude a red pointer shows the exact position on the map.

But when i use this URL in my phonegap build app, it shows only the map, not the red pointer for exact position.

```
<a href="geo:38.897096,-77.036545">map</a>
```

My question is, How i get the red pointer by my URL ?

map

Comment: The map link doesn't show as part of your question.

Comment: I am in mobile view so facing some problems to show the actual html code for this link